# Can someone tell me how to run a batch file from Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I thought I could run a batch file from Notepad++ directly using nppexec by (or the built in run command) by typing CMD $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)

But since notepad++ HAS a CMD command (which open the cmd shell in the npp console) then it is not working.  So running the above command opens cmd shell in the npp console but does not run the batch file.  At that point I can run $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH) AND it will run the batch file.  But then I have to type exit to get our of command shell mode.

Can someone tell me how to run the batch file I am current editing in npp directly in npp.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
cmd /c "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

:)

Comment: +1, this works for me, also found out that you can save this command from the Run dialog, and it will automatically appear on the Run menu

Comment: If you want it to run in the path of the file: `cmd /c "cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) && $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

Answer (score 24):

With [RunMe](https://sites.google.com/site/fstellari/nppplugins) plugin you can do this. It can change current directory to the file path before open the file and Ben's solution doesn't do this. ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
cmd /k "cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) && "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"" & pause
```

This catches Batch files with spaces in it.

Comment: The *pause* is a nice addition.  Sometimes I like hearing a **bell** when a batch file completes.  The entry screen wouldn't let me type ALT+007 but I was able to edit the *shortcuts.xml* file and add `echo &#x0007;` to it.   In the XML file my full command is now `cmd /k &quot;cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) &amp;&amp; &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;&quot; &amp; echo &#x0007; &amp; echo Press any key to return to Notepad++... &amp; pause&gt;nul &amp; Exit`

Answer (score 3):

To run batch within its parent directory, you have to pass `/d` param to `cd` to change drive letter if needed and and escape paths(if contains spaces).

```
cmd /c "cd /d ""$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"" && ""$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"""
```

Comment: When I try this, I get a flash of a cmd window, then it's gone, even though I have a pause statement in my batch file, and the batch file doesn't execute.

Comment: @SirAdelaide You can add " & pause", at the end of run command (not batch file) to pause and see why batch failed to run.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the run menu in notepad++ to create shortcuts:

1. Run -> Run (F5)
2. Type command line into "The Program to Run"
3. Save, type the name (choose the shortcut if you need)

**With me:**

[link to example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaWha.png)

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:commit /path:"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:lock /path:"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:unlock /path:"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:log /path:"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```